# OpenTelemetry AWS XRay Exporter

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, open-telemetry, aws-xray

Noob question here. I'm sending x-ray data to an Opentelemetry Collector so the receiver is awsxray. But when it is exported by the awsxray exporter, it does not show a complete trace. Is there something missing in what I'm doing?

It should be something like this:

Service A -> Service B -> Service C

Instead, I'm getting this:

Service A

Service B

Service C

Here's the configuration that I'm currently using:

```yaml
receivers:
  awsxray:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:2000

exporters:
  awsxray:
    region: us-east-1

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [awsxray]
      exporters: [awsxray]
```

Comment: Can you enable debug-level logging and share the collector logs please?

Comment: It only shows the `TracesExporter#011{"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "logging", "#spans": 26}`. But the traces seem a little bit weird. From the original x-ray data it shows something like this: `Client -> Api Gateway -> Lambda -> X Service`. But when it was exported, it was `Client -> Api Gateway -> Lambda`. The service inside the lambda is gone.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit with the ask. What I meant by enable debug level logging was: 

```
exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug
service:
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: debug
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [awsxray]
      exporters: [awsxray, logging]
```